# Emacs+Slime inferior-lisp exited abnormally with code 5

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

I try to install slime in emacs. I follow many manuals and got one oucome.

"M-x slime" trow exeption "process inferior-lisp exited abnormally with code 5"

- OS Windows 8.1
- GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of
  2018-05-30
- SBCL 1.4.2
- SLIME 2.22

My .emacs file text

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "C:/SBCL/sbcl.exe") 
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/slime/") 
(require 'slime)
```

Following the comment, I tried to understand where the installation falls

```
-(load #P"C:/slime/swank-loader")
-T
-(swank-loader::init :reload t)
-WARNING: redefining EMACS-INSPECT (#(SB-PCL:SYSTEM-CLASS COMMON-LISP:T)) in DEFMETHOD
NIL 
-(swank:create-server :port 7777)

;;Swank started at port:7777

In Emacs
-M-x slime-connect
Host: localhost
Port: 7777

-Lisp connection closed unexpectedly: connection broken by remote peer
```

In other topics where i saw that error message, peoples run complex sourcecode with mistakes. The problem was solved by correcting errors. It seems like different situation or i don't understand something.

Comment: I am not using Windows 8 but would suggested you give [portacle](https://portacle.github.io/) a try. It has everything for starting CL you need bundled. Futhermore, you could check the SBCL mailing list as it seems to be an issue with the windows port.

Comment: Thank you, this is really userfriendly.

Comment: Maybe change `SWANK:*COMMUNICATION-STYLE*` to one of `NIL`, `:FD-HANDLER`, `:SIGIO` instead of the default `:SPAWN`. Do not load any user-init file.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

You need to find out at which layer the problem occurs. Try for example to run SBCL in a shell with the same command-line (e.g. `C:/SBCL/sbcl.exe`); if it works, in the REPL:

```
CL-USER> (load #P"C:/slime/swank-loader")
```

If that works, you can manually init the swank backend (the Common Lisp part of the Slime/Swank protocol).

```
CL-USER> (swank-loader::init :reload t)
```

Then, try to start a server (the port value is arbitrary):

```
CL-USER> (swank:create-server :port 7777)
```

If a server starts, you can try to run `slime-connect` from Emacs, using the localhost port and the same port.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I performed these steps and added results in first message because this is too long for comment too.

Answer (score 1):

Oleg, try to give ip address 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost when doing `slime-connect`. I have similar problem on OSX when connecting to a remote SLIME server.

Comment: Nothing has changed =(